# Pass function arguments that are variable names into formulae in R functions?

Tags: r, function, arguments, formula

I am looking for a simple way to pass function arguments that are variable names into formulae in R functions.

Test dataset:

```
set.seed(4892)
df.pass <- data.frame("alfa"=sample(1:9, 100, replace=T), "beta"=sample(1:9, 100, replace=T), 
                      "theta"=sample(1:9, 100, replace=T), "out"=runif(100, 0, 1))
```

Example analysis (testing if interaction model is different) to be made into function:

```
lrtest(glm(out~alfa*beta, family = binomial("logit"), df.pass),
       glm(out~alfa + beta, family = binomial("logit"), df.pass))
```

If the goal is to create the generic function `invinteract` that solves the problem above with arbitrary variable names and data sets, what would be the simplest way to pass variable names from `function()` arguments to formulae terms corresponding to  the positions of `out`, `alfa` and `beta`?

Inserting the raw variable names into the formulae does not work, because R tries to evaluate the names as objects and finds nothing.

Inserting string variable names directly into formulae does not work either.

Is it necessary to reconstruct the formulae with `paste()`, or is there a more direct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glm` also accepts a character string instead of a formula. Thus, you can do this:

```
mytest <- function(DF, y, x1, x2) {
  lrtest(glm(sprintf("%s ~ %s * %s", y, x1, x2), family = binomial("logit"), DF),
         glm(sprintf("%s ~ %s + %s", y, x1, x2), family = binomial("logit"), DF))
}
mytest(df.pass, "out", "alfa", "beta")
```

Comment: Thanks! That is a really neat solution. The sprintf() notation makes it quite clean compared with a succession of paste() uses